# ASP.Net Medium trust and dll

Tags: asp.net, permissions

I have an ASP.Net website and add a reference to my dll. Medium trust permission level is set for the web site.
During web site compilation i get the exception:

Could not load file or assembly ... or one of its dependencies. Failed to grant minimum permission requests.

What should i change in my dll to make it work in Medium trust level ?

Comment: It would help if you were more specific about what it is your DLL does (or what external dependencies it has).

Comment: it have dependencies only on .NET Framework libraries: System.Data, System.Xml, System.Web and a few others.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your DLL is doing. Here are some of the restrictions applied under Medium Trust:

- Permissions are limited in what the application can access within its own
  directory structure
- No file access is permitted
  outside of the application's virtual directory hierarchy
- Limited
  rights to certain common environment variables
- No reflection
  permissions
- No sockets permission
- To access Web resources,
  you must explicitly add endpoint 'URLs' - either in the originUrl
  attribute of the element or inside the policy file

Comment: Thank you. But i noticed that if some of this restrictions are broken, an exception will appear when a code that breaks that restriction start to execute. But not during compilation.

Comment: But does your DLL violate any of these constraints?